# Highlight Cells Rules Text contains

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have the following function =AND(EXACT(B3;F3);EXACT(F3;J3)) which returns TRUE or FALSE.
I'd like to create a cell rule for coloring red the false and green the true values.
Trying to use the following code, but not working, what am i doing wrong?

```
   Excel.FormatConditions fcs = xlWorkSheet.Cells[i,"M"].FormatConditions;
                    Excel.FormatCondition fc = (Excel.FormatCondition)fcs.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlTextString, Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, "TRUE");
                    Excel.Interior interior = fc.Interior;
                    interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.LightGreen);
                    Excel.Font font = fc.Font;
                    font.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.ForestGreen);
                    fc = (Excel.FormatCondition)fcs.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlTextString, Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, "FALSE");
                    interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.LightSalmon);
                    font.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);
```

Comment: To allow @chewmewaba4 to write what he/she wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not associating the colors with the given rules (but with variables not related to the Conditional Formatting). Also you should better rely on `xlCellValue`. This code delivers what you are after:

```
Excel.FormatCondition fc = (Excel.FormatCondition)fcs.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, "TRUE", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
fc.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.LightGreen);
fc.Font.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.ForestGreen);

fc = (Excel.FormatCondition)fcs.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, "FALSE", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
fc.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.LightSalmon);
fc.Font.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but after using the condition it cannot save the xls

   xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Update_Report.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
Guess its issue for old format

Comment: @SzabolcsSzrenko I open a xls file, write my code and Save() this file, I don't have any problem. Please, bear in mind that you asked why your formatting wasn't working and this is working now. If you want to inquire about further issues (regarding Excel automation or anythingg else) you should post a new question. I wouldn't mind to help you a bit out, but from what you are saying it seems like you need more than a couple of isolated tips. The code I wrote does not have any effect outside the given range (Cells[i,"M"]). You might have to adapt it to your specific conditions, but nothing else.

Comment: Yeah, you right. Sorry for the mass question and ofc appreciate your help!

Comment: @SzabolcsSzrenko No problem. I intended to start answering but, while doing it, I realised that I needed further info (= better a new question).

Answer (score 0):

(Apologize for posting this as an answer, but I don't have enough rep to add a comment yet)
You have line:

```
Excel.FormatCondition fc = (Excel.FormatCondition)fcs.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlTextString, Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, "TRUE");
```

And your third parameter "TRUE" would normally represent the formula.  If you want this to work, you'll need to change it to "=TRUE".  Similarly, you have "FALSE" which should be updated to "=FALSE".

You'll also want to include @varocarbas suggestions above.

Comment: You can try to write your comment now (I think that you can post comments, after someone has written something). He does not need to write "=True". The reason why his code does not work is because of the reasons I explained: he is not associating the colors to the conditions (just to external variables) and thus no color modification can happen. And he relies on a XlFormatConditionType which, at least on my computer, triggers an error (the logical one is xlCellValue). Please write anything you want via comment (you can now) and delete this answer if you don't think that should be here.